# When migrating a Rails 3 app to Rails 4.2, index.html.erb renders a blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to migrate a Rails 3 application to Rails 4.2.10. However, when i run rake migrations and pre-compile assets, the rendered welcome page is blank.

routes.rb

```
root :to => 'welcome#index'
get "/privacy" => 'welcome#privacy'
get "/help" => 'welcome#help'
resources :user_sessions
```

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_login

  def index
    cookies.delete :range
    cookies.delete :lat_lng 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :nothing => true }
    end
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html # index.html.erb
    #   format.json { render json: @faces }
    # end
  end

  def privacy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # privacy.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @faces }
    end
  end

  def help
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # help.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @faces }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The commented code will look for an actual index.html.erb. The code that is uncommented, just says `render nothing: true`, an empty response.

Comment: It is actually rendering a blank page, when I want javascript to load a page.

Comment: You are not responding to js, maybe add an empty `format.js` for it to look at a _index.js.erb_? And be sure to request JS and not HTML.

Comment: index.html includes this code. which loads the javascript file, which redirects to posts.html.  

<%= javascript_include_tag "locate.js" %>
<div data-role="header" data-id="persistheader" data-position="fixed"> 
 <h1>GeoFly.me</h1> 
 </div>
<%= render "shared/login" %>

 
function displayPosition(position) {

  setGeoCookie(position);
  var sliderValue = document.getElementById('slider-fill').value
  setRangeCookie(sliderValue);
  window.location.href =  'https://geofly.me/posts.html';

Comment: Has your original problem been resolved? Rendering all that HTML to later redirect back to the user, seems wrong, but that's tangential to the question being asked. If you have additional questions, post other and we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote def index as follows:

```
def index
    cookies.delete :range
    cookies.delete :lat_lng 
    [snip]
    [snip]

    end
end
```

render nothing was deprecated in RoR 4. By deleting the two statements entirely, it accomplished the same thing.